# Converting string to array using filter and using it in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a string which is in "1200:2,1300:3,1400:2" format. I need this to be printed like

```
 <p>1200</p><p>2</p>
 <p>1300</p><p>3</p>
 <p>1400</p><p>2</p>
```

I tried using filter,

```
return function (input) {
                //Validate the input
                if (!input) {
                    return '';
                }
                var hoaArray = [];
                var inputArray = input.split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                    var adminTimeArray = inputArray[i].split(':');
                    hoaArray.push({ 'adminTime': adminTimeArray[0], 'dose': adminTimeArray[1]?adminTimeArray[1]:'' });
                }
                return hoaArray;
            };
```

and inside html like

```
<p ng-repeat="timing in timing_list | formatter">{{timing.}}</p>{{timing .adminTime}}</div>
```

I am getting the following error,

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":36,"oldVal":34}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":38,"oldVal":36}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":40,"oldVal":38}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":42,"oldVal":40}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":44,"oldVal":42}]]

Could anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Raaj

Comment: After roaming around, found a solution (I am not sure). Used ng-init for temporarily storing the formatted array on the parent tag, and used ng-init variable for the iteration,                                                        `<label ng-init="timingArray = (timing_list | formatter)">Timing:</label>
                                <p ng-repeat="timing in timingArray track by $id(timing)">
                                    {{timing.adminTime}} : {{timing.dose}}
                                </p>`

Answer (score 0):

In the IndexController.js file:

```
 var inputString = "1200:2,1330:3,1400:4,1500:3";

    var formatInputString = function (input) {
        //Validate the input
        if (!input) {
            return '';
        }
        var hoaArray = [];
        var inputArray = input.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            var adminTimeArray = inputArray[i].split(':');
            hoaArray.push({ 'adminTime': adminTimeArray[0], 'dose': adminTimeArray[1] ? adminTimeArray[1] : '' });
        }
        return hoaArray;
    };

    $scope.inputString = inputString;
    $scope.formattedString = formatInputString(inputString);
```

In the HTML file:

```
<div ng-repeat="timing in formattedString" >
    {{timing.adminTime}}
    {{timing.dose}}
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought of this, but since it is just one property inside a large JSON array. So I tried not to make it more attached to a specific screen but to make it more generic so that I could re-use it and more maintainable

Comment: can you paste your JSON response here?

Comment: it contains some sensitive information, which I cannot paste it here. Sorry

Comment: paste an example (strip out the sensitive info), just want to get the general format of your JSON

Answer (score 0):

The issue here - possibly a limitation or a bug in Angular - is that your filter creates new array objects every time it runs. `ng-repeat` uses [under the covers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L384) `$scope.$watchCollection` to watch for the expression `"timing_list | formatter"` - this watcher always trips up because, in trying to detect a change in a values in the collection, it compares objects with a simple `"!=="` - and the objects are always new and different objects.

In short, this is another way to reproduce:

```
$scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.$watchCollection("items | foo", function(){
});
```

where `foo` is a filter that operates on each element in the array creating a new object:

```
.filter("foo", function(){
  return function(inputArray){
    return inputArray.map(function(item){
      return {a: item};
    });
  };
});
```

So, to answer your question - you cannot with Angular v1.3.15 use a filter that returns an array with objects (without some funky object caching) with `$watchCollection`, and by extension, with `ng-repeat`.

The best way is to create the array first (with `ng-init` or in the controller), and then use it in the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Raajkumar, good... at least you know that there isn't any other easier way